# Is there a way to retrieve the data from a BART package model in R?

Tags: r, bart

I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve the data from a model built from the `BART` package in R?

It seems to be possible using other bart packages, such as `dbarts`... but I can't seem to find a way to get the original data back from a `BART` model. For example, if I create some data and run a `BART` and `dbarts` model, like so:

```
library(BART)
library(dbarts)

# create data
df <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100),
  y = runif(100),
  z = runif(100)
)

# create BART
BARTmodel <- wbart(x.train = df[,1:2],
                   y.train = df[,3])

# create dbarts
DBARTSmodel <- bart(x.train = df[,1:2],
                    y.train = df[,3],
                    keeptrees = TRUE)
```

Using the `keeptrees` option in `dbarts` allows me to retrieve the data using:

```
# retrieve data from dbarts
DBARTSmodel$fit$data@x
```

However, there doesn't seem to be any type of similar option when using `BART`. Is it even possible to retrieve the data from a `BART` model?

Comment: I think that you can get what you are looking for with the function `bartModelMatrix` using `df` as argument. This will retrieve you a matrix with the same values from `DBARTSmodel$fit$data@x` the only change I see it's that the function `bartModelMatrix` creates you a matrix for each column in `df`  so you get a matrix of 3 columns (`x`, `y` and `z`) instead of 2 from `DBARTSmodel$fit$data@x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Value:` section of `?wbart` suggests it doesn't return the input as part of the output, and none of the function arguments for `wbart` suggest that this can be changed.

Furthermore, if you look at the output of `str`, you can see that it's not present.

```r
library(BART)
library(dbarts)

# create data
df <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100),
  y = runif(100),
  z = runif(100)
)

# create BART
BARTmodel <- wbart(x.train = df[,1:2],
                   y.train = df[,3])

# create dbarts
DBARTSmodel <- bart(x.train = df[,1:2],
                    y.train = df[,3],
                    keeptrees = TRUE)

str(BARTmodel)
#> List of 13
#>  $ sigma          : num [1:1100] 0.258 0.262 0.295 0.278 0.273 ...
#>  $ yhat.train.mean: num [1:100] 0.584 0.457 0.505 0.54 0.403 ...
#>  $ yhat.train     : num [1:1000, 1:100] 0.673 0.62 0.433 0.711 0.634 ...
#>  $ yhat.test.mean : num(0) 
#>  $ yhat.test      : num[1:1000, 0 ] 
#>  $ varcount       : int [1:1000, 1:2] 109 114 111 118 115 114 115 110 114 117 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : NULL
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
#>  $ varprob        : num [1:1000, 1:2] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : NULL
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
#>  $ treedraws      :List of 2
#>   ..$ cutpoints:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ x: num [1:100] 0.0147 0.0245 0.0343 0.0442 0.054 ...
#>   .. ..$ y: num [1:100] 0.0395 0.0491 0.0586 0.0681 0.0776 ...
#>   ..$ trees    : chr "1000 200 2\n1\n1 0 0 0.01185590432\n3\n1 1 30 -0.01530736435\n2 0 0 0.01064412946\n3 0 0 0.02413784284\n3\n1 0 "| __truncated__
#>  $ proc.time      : 'proc_time' Named num [1:5] 1.406 0.008 1.415 0 0
#>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "user.self" "sys.self" "elapsed" "user.child" ...
#>  $ mu             : num 0.501
#>  $ varcount.mean  : Named num [1:2] 115 110
#>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x" "y"
#>  $ varprob.mean   : Named num [1:2] 0.5 0.5
#>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x" "y"
#>  $ rm.const       : int [1:2] 1 2
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "wbart"
```

Whereas the output of `str()` for the `bart` output, while long, does contain the input:

```r
str(DBARTSmodel)
#> List of 11
#>  $ call           : language bart(x.train = df[, 1:2], y.train = df[, 3], keeptrees = TRUE)
#>  $ first.sigma    : num [1:100] 0.289 0.311 0.268 0.253 0.242 ...
#>  $ sigma          : num [1:1000] 0.288 0.307 0.248 0.257 0.293 ...
#>  $ sigest         : num 0.295
#>  $ yhat.train     : num [1:1000, 1:100] 0.715 0.677 0.508 0.51 0.827 ...
#>  $ yhat.train.mean: num [1:100] 0.583 0.456 0.504 0.544 0.404 ...
#>  $ yhat.test      : NULL
#>  $ yhat.test.mean : NULL
#>  $ varcount       : int [1:1000, 1:2] 128 118 120 142 130 145 145 150 138 138 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : NULL
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
#>  $ y              : num [1:100] 0.8489 0.0817 0.4371 0.8566 0.0878 ...
#>  $ fit            :Reference class 'dbartsSampler' [package "dbarts"] with 5 fields
#>   ..$ pointer:<externalptr> 
#>   ..$ control:Formal class 'dbartsControl' [package "dbarts"] with 18 slots
#>   .. .. ..@ binary          : logi FALSE
#>   .. .. ..@ verbose         : logi TRUE
#>   .. .. ..@ keepTrainingFits: logi TRUE
#>   .. .. ..@ useQuantiles    : logi FALSE
#>   .. .. ..@ keepTrees       : logi TRUE
#>   .. .. ..@ n.samples       : int 1000
#>   .. .. ..@ n.burn          : int 100
#>   .. .. ..@ n.trees         : int 200
#>   .. .. ..@ n.chains        : int 1
#>   .. .. ..@ n.threads       : int 1
#>   .. .. ..@ n.thin          : int 1
#>   .. .. ..@ printEvery      : int 100
#>   .. .. ..@ printCutoffs    : int 0
#>   .. .. ..@ rngKind         : chr "default"
#>   .. .. ..@ rngNormalKind   : chr "default"
#>   .. .. ..@ rngSeed         : int NA
#>   .. .. ..@ updateState     : logi TRUE
#>   .. .. ..@ call            : language bart(x.train = df[, 1:2], y.train = df[, 3], keeptrees = TRUE)
#>   ..$ model  :Formal class 'dbartsModel' [package "dbarts"] with 9 slots
#>   .. .. ..@ p.birth_death  : num 0.5
#>   .. .. ..@ p.swap         : num 0.1
#>   .. .. ..@ p.change       : num 0.4
#>   .. .. ..@ p.birth        : num 0.5
#>   .. .. ..@ node.scale     : num 0.5
#>   .. .. ..@ tree.prior     :Formal class 'dbartsCGMPrior' [package "dbarts"] with 3 slots
#>   .. .. .. .. ..@ power             : num 2
#>   .. .. .. .. ..@ base              : num 0.95
#>   .. .. .. .. ..@ splitProbabilities: num(0) 
#>   .. .. ..@ node.prior     :Formal class 'dbartsNormalPrior' [package "dbarts"] with 0 slots
#>  list()
#>   .. .. ..@ node.hyperprior:Formal class 'dbartsFixedHyperprior' [package "dbarts"] with 1 slot
#>   .. .. .. .. ..@ k: num 2
#>   .. .. ..@ resid.prior    :Formal class 'dbartsChiSqPrior' [package "dbarts"] with 2 slots
#>   .. .. .. .. ..@ df      : num 3
#>   .. .. .. .. ..@ quantile: num 0.9
#>   ..$ data   :Formal class 'dbartsData' [package "dbarts"] with 10 slots
#>   .. .. ..@ y                    : num [1:100] 0.8489 0.0817 0.4371 0.8566 0.0878 ...
#>   .. .. ..@ x                    : num [1:100, 1:2] 0.152 0.666 0.967 0.248 0.668 ...
#>   .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
#>   .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
#>   .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "drop")=List of 2
#>   .. .. .. .. ..$ x: logi FALSE
#>   .. .. .. .. ..$ y: logi FALSE
#>   .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:2] "x" "y"
#>   .. .. ..@ varTypes             : int [1:2] 0 0
#>   .. .. ..@ x.test               : NULL
#>   .. .. ..@ weights              : NULL
#>   .. .. ..@ offset               : NULL
#>   .. .. ..@ offset.test          : NULL
#>   .. .. ..@ n.cuts               : int [1:2] 100 100
#>   .. .. ..@ sigma                : num 0.295
#>   .. .. ..@ testUsesRegularOffset: logi NA
#>   ..$ state  :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ :Formal class 'dbartsState' [package "dbarts"] with 6 slots
#>   .. .. .. ..@ trees     : int [1:1055] 0 18 -1 0 49 -1 -1 0 60 -1 ...
#>   .. .. .. ..@ treeFits  : num [1:100, 1:200] -0.02252 0.00931 0.00931 0.02688 0.00931 ...
#>   .. .. .. ..@ savedTrees: int [1:2340360] 0 797997482 1070928224 1 -402902351 1070268808 -1 -1094651769 -1081938039 -1 ...
#>   .. .. .. ..@ sigma     : num 0.297
#>   .. .. .. ..@ k         : num 2
#>   .. .. .. ..@ rng.state : int [1:18] 0 1078575104 0 1078575104 -1657977906 1075613906 0 1078558720 277209871 -1068236140 ...
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "runningTime")= num 0.477
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "currentNumSamples")= int 1000
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "currentSampleNum")= int 0
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "numCuts")= int [1:2] 100 100
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "cutPoints")=List of 2
#>   .. .. ..$ : num [1:100] 0.0147 0.0245 0.0343 0.0442 0.054 ...
#>   .. .. ..$ : num [1:100] 0.0395 0.0491 0.0586 0.0681 0.0776 ...
#>   ..and 40 methods, of which 26 are  possibly relevant:
#>   ..  copy#envRefClass, getLatents, getPointer, getTrees, initialize, plotTree,
#>   ..  predict, printTrees, run, sampleNodeParametersFromPrior,
#>   ..  sampleTreesFromPrior, setControl, setCutPoints, setData, setModel,
#>   ..  setOffset, setPredictor, setResponse, setSigma, setState, setTestOffset,
#>   ..  setTestPredictor, setTestPredictorAndOffset, setWeights,
#>   ..  show#envRefClass, storeState
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "bart"
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, seems to be the case. As your answer directly answers my question, I'm selecting this as the accepted answer.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are looking for using `bartModelMatrix()` function form `BART` package.

> This function it will determinate the number of cutpoints necessary for each column.

In this way, you'll have so many columns as variables you have in your `df`.
In your example you're only insterested in `x` and `y`, so you'll only care for the first and second column from `bartModelMatrix()` matrix obtained.

So for the example you gave:

```
# create data
df <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100),
  y = runif(100),
  z = runif(100),
)

# create BART
BARTmodel <- wbart(x.train = df[,1:2],
                   y.train = df[,3])

# create dbarts
DBARTSmodel <- bart(x.train = df[,1:2],
                    y.train = df[,3],
                    keeptrees = TRUE)


BARTmatrix <- bartModelMatrix(df) 
BARTmatrix <- BARTmatrix[,1:2]

BARTmatrix == DBARTSmodel$fit$data@x
```

Hope that helped you

Comment: Apologies, I don't think I was super clear in my question. The issue here is that you still have to pass the original data frame `df` as an argument to `bartModelMatrix`. I am creating a function that uses the output of a `wbart` model and I was hoping to avoid having to add an argument for the data to my function. 
Whereas with `dbarts`, I can extract the data directly from the model output. It seems like I can't do this directly from the `BART` package.